# Marklogic wildcarded search false positives issue ( SQL like %something% equivalent )

Tags: search, xquery, wildcard, marklogic

I have a question regarding the behavior of the wildcarded search in MarkLogic.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to replicate the SQL like %something% query.

Here is the code that returns false positives:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
cts:search(/, 
  cts:element-query(fn:QName("","Document"),
  cts:element-word-query(fn:QName("","Information"),"*date*", ("wildcarded"),0), ()),
  'unfiltered')
```

A few notes:

- The unfiltered option must stay, because performance is necessary.
- I am using the Unicode Collation and have enabled :

  - three character searches
  - trailing wildcard searches
  - fast element trailing wildcard searches
  - two character searches
  - one character searches
  - fast element character searches

What I don't understand is why "*something" and "something*" return correct values, but "*something*" returns false positives? How can I fix this?

Input example:

1. `<Document><Information>another updated document</Information></Document>`
2. `<Document><Information>INCUMBENCY CERTIFICATE</Information></Document>`
3. `<Document><Information>Certificate of Incumbency</Information></Document>`
4. `<Document><Information>something 344_dated 243</Information></Document>`
5. `<Document><Information>another terminated document</Information></Document>`

Output:

All documents are a match, although only 1 and 4 should be returned.

Final edit: The only thing I would like to add is that it seemed that on two databases - one with a heavier load of documents, the same settings did not generate the same results. On the database with lots of documents, the final settings that I used and which give the correct results are :

- word searches
- word positions
- triple index
- fast element word searches
- element word positions
- fast element phrase searches
- three character searches
- three character word positions
- fast element character searches
- trailing wildcard searches
- trailing wildcard word positions
- fast element trailing wildcard searches
- word lexicon : codepoint collation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfiltered wildcard queries within specific elements (i.e. not just with a document) may return false positives without positional indexes. I would try enabling either or both of `word positions` and `element word positions`. It may also be worth testing whether you see additional performance improvements from enabling `fast element phrase searches`.

It's possible that simply because "*something and something*" contains more terms it is filtering out false positives and not because it is more accurately resolving that phrase though indexes.

**Update:** After reviewing your updated test case, it appears that trailing wildcard index accuracy is not good enough without `trailing wildcard word positions` enabled. That and `three character word positions` appear to be necessary to resolve this type of leading-and-trailing element wildcard query.

I would recommend disabling `one character searches` and `two character searches` if they are not strictly necessary, since they will generate large indexes. `fast element character searches` and `fast element trailing wildcard searches` also do not appear to be required for accuracy in your case, so you might want to test if your queries are fast enough without them.

Comment: Sorry, my initial wording was inaccurate. I edited the post to explain that I meant "\*something" and "something\*" as separate inputs. I don't think the word position index would help in this case, but I will try it, thank you!

Comment: @MB The word position indexes are used to determine where a word lies specifically within a document, which is why they may be necessary for accurate unfiltered element queries, regardless of whether the query terms include a phrase (for which positional indexes can also help accuracy).

Comment: Unfortunately, wrong results still appear even after setting word positions and element word positions on. Fast element phrase searches is also set to true. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @MB You're sure reindexing was complete before testing? And the same query `filtered` returned different/correct results? I'm not sure what else to suggest without a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, reindexing was complete before testing. I even forced a reindex on the whole database just to be sure. The same query, but with 'filtered' returns the correct results.

Comment: I added in the question the input/output and modified to the exact query.

Comment: @MB Finally had a chance to test this, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

While using the cts:element-value-query, did you tried using the "exact" options to get your exact results ?
Try using that once and let me know how it behaves. I have faced a similar issue once.

Comment: The `exact` option is mutually exclusive of `wildcarded`, which is an important requirement of the question.

Comment: For sanity check, dont assume that unfiltered is *always needed* for efficient queries.  I suggest trying a filtered query to first validate you get correct results,  then depending performance, look at the query plan and see if you can reduce the amount of 'filtering' needed -- If the resolved search is only a few documents (out of many in the corpus) -- a filtered query may be nearly as fast as an unfiltered one.